# Why do I keep getting this error message when I try to insert something into a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers, insert

Here is the question that I have to answer:

7. Create a trigger named Products_INSERT that inserts the current date for the DateAdded column of the Products table if the value for that column is null.
   Test this trigger with an appropriate INSERT statement.

Here is the code that I have:

```
    CREATE TRIGGER Products_INSERT
        ON Products
        AFTER INSERT
    AS
        UPDATE Products
        SET DateAdded = GETDATE()
        WHERE DateAdded IS NULL OR
              DateAdded IN (SELECT DateAdded FROM inserted);
```

Here is my insert statement:

```
    INSERT INTO Products
    VALUES (4, 'LK-5300', 'Likeable Keyboard 5300',
    'This keyboard is so cool, you just might flip!',
    699.99, 30.00, NULL)
```

And here is the error I keep getting:

```
    Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
    The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK__Products__Catego__145C0A3F". The conflict occurred in database "MyGuitarShop", table "dbo.Categories", column 'CategoryID'.
    The statement has been terminated.
```

I know that the error has something to do with the foreign key but I'm not entirely sure.  Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT:

```
    CREATE TABLE Products (
      ProductID         INT            PRIMARY KEY   IDENTITY,
      CategoryID        INT            REFERENCES Categories (CategoryID), 
      ProductCode       VARCHAR(10)    NOT NULL      UNIQUE,
      ProductName       VARCHAR(255)   NOT NULL,
      Description       TEXT           NOT NULL,
      ListPrice         MONEY          NOT NULL,
      DiscountPercent   MONEY          NOT NULL      DEFAULT 0.00,
      DateAdded         DATETIME                     DEFAULT NULL
      );
```

Here is the Products table

Comment: you will probably need to show us the description of the products table... and especially that foreign key constraint it's complaining about.

Comment: firstly, this can't be both mysql and sql-server. secondly, it looks like you're trying to add a product with a non existent category

Comment: Does it work without the trigger? Seems like that might be a red herring and the problem lies with the product table

Comment: Make sure that you have the value `LK-5300` added to the `Categories` table before trying to insert the same `CategoryID` into `Products` table.

Comment: The LK-5300 would be the ProductCode

Comment: Do you have CategoryID 4 in the Categories table?

Comment: It would be so much easier if I could show a snip-it of the Categories table but I don't have enough rep.  There are four CategoryID's 1111, 2222, 3333, and 4444.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your `INSERT` should be:

```
INSERT INTO Products
  (   CategoryID,
      ProductCode,
      ProductName,
      Description,
      ListPrice,
      DiscountPercent,
      DateAdded
   )   
    VALUES (4, 'LK-5300', 'Likeable Keyboard 5300',
    'This keyboard is so cool, you just might flip!',
    699.99, 30.00, NULL)
```

Your INSERT was missing a value to go into the `ProductID` column, since it is auto-generated because it is defined as IDENTITY but to get that to work, you need to name the columns, leaving out `ProductID`.

Comment: actually it is not mandatory to name columns as far as ordering of other columns are valid. The real error was about incorrect categoryid. I dont know why this answer was accepted. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/da7b2/2

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri Thanks for the correction, I put a comment under Joshua's answer. I might delete this answer so it doesn't mislead anyone.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to include the productID because its auto generated

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33169517)

Answer (score 0):

Thank's @Turophile here a what I ended up doing to my INSERT statement after I read your post:

```
    INSERT INTO Products (CategoryID, ProductCode, ProductName, Description, ListPrice,DiscountPercent, DateAdded)
    VALUES (44444, 'LK-5300', 'Likeable Keyboard 5300',
    'This keyboard is so cool, you just might flip!',
     699.99, 30.00, NULL)
```

Comment: As @GiorgiNakeuri has pointed out on a comment to my answer, I mistakenly thought that the error was because you weren't supplying a value for the `ProductID` column (because it was generated), but SQL Server was consequently assigning the values into the wrong columns. As shown in this fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/29219/1 that is not the case, if you change the first value 4 -> 5 it will not work. This illustrating the actual problem that your Categories table has the value 44444 in it, but not the value 4 (which you were originally inserting) and thus the FK constraint was triggered.